# Get list of all registered sidebars

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I am registering sidebars automatically for each category (a separate widget space per category).  The technique I'm using is **[here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-register-one-sidebar-for-widgets-per-category?replies=4#post-1120013)**.

In the admin side I have an options page where I need to display a dropdown of all registered sidebars... Is there are way to dynamically get this list of registered sidebars?  since they're being registered in functions.php I assume they're in memory, not in the database.

I could keep track of the sidebars I register in some global variable, but just in case plugins register their own sidebars, I'd like to account for them too.

I'll dig through the core if I have to, but thought someone might know off-hand:)

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hmm... I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but it's simple:

I looked in `register_sidebar()` and found that new sidebars are simply tacked onto an array:`$wp_registered_sidebars`

And I guess that's that.  If they ever change the name of the variable, I guess I'd be screwed.

Comment: You can always access it via $GLOBALS['wp_registered_sidebars']. In case that changes, you can in your plugin just run a search and replace - and it didn't change since it has been introduced as far as I can remember.